# Winter Bash 2016: Do we want hats?

Tags: discussion

It's that time of year again!

> The year is rapidly coming to a close, which means even though we typically [hate it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/268583#268583), it’s time to have some fun...with hats!  That’s right - **it’s time for Winter Bash 2016!!**
>
> **Overview**
>
> Most of you remember previous years’ events, but here is a quick little reminder. Winter Bash is an annual event that can run on any Stack Exchange site that chooses to participate. Users have fun by earning “hats” for their gravatars by completing certain tasks (very similar to badges). We track everyone’s progress using hats in a leaderboard that looks similar to this:
>
> [image: Winter Bash 2016 Leaderboard]
>
> As always, we’re coming up with new hat designs for this year’s fun!
>
> **The Details**
>
> The event will run from **19 December 2016** up to and including **08 January 2017**. Users will be able to see all the hats they’ve earned on http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com. That site will also have a landing page, explaining the rules and other details of the event.
>
> Individual users who don’t want to participate, don’t want to see hats, and/or are generally anti-hat will have an “I hate hats” option available. And just like last time, **at the end of the event, all hats will go back into storage.**
>
> The only visual change to the Stack Exchange sites themselves will be the presence of the hats and the “I hate hats” button in the footer.

So...hats or no hats? We have until **Tuesday, 13 December 2016** to decide.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes please! Here are some alternate astronaut hats.
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: ....AstronHats!

Answer (score 16):

Of course we want hats! Why are you asking?

Answer (score 8):

**Yes,** but only if there's an astronaut helmet that can be earned somehow!

(Just kidding about that last. Of course we want hats.)

Comment: I'll ping the staff and see what we can do;-)

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto Thanks, I was about to say the same.

Comment: Semi-seriously (as serious as can be in a question about winter bash), an astronaut helmet hat would be cool.

Comment: Jon bows out, but says: "As a peace offering, here's one of our developers talking about landing the Space Shuttle: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jb4prVsXkZU  "

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto Talk is cheap.

Answer (score 7):

I for one welcome our haberdashing overlords!

Answer (score 3):

Of course we need hats in the winter!

[image]